# Unable to read from Process.StandardOutput

Tags: c#, process

I am trying to use a [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) to check the version of Java installed using the "-version" command line parameter. However when I try to read the command line output from the java application I get a null value.

My code is fairly simple:

```
Process java = new Process();
java.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
java.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
java.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
java.StartInfo.FileName = "java";
java.StartInfo.Arguments = "-version";
java.Start();

// version comes out null
string version = java.StandardOutput.ReadLine();

// There are probably better ways to extract this data but
// I want to get it working before I cross that bridge.
string versionNumber = version.Substring(16, 1);
hasJava = int.Parse(versionNumber) < 7;

java.Close();
```

It is probably something small and easy, but I can't see it.

Comment: does it come out null? or does it come out empty?

Comment: @SamIam null, if it was empty I would assume that java just writes an empty like and try another ReadLine()

Comment: I've found something that works on my machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, I've found that the information you're looking for, for some reason, can be found in the `standardError` stream.

try the following.

```
Process java = new Process();
java.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
java.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
java.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
java.StartInfo.FileName = "java";
java.StartInfo.Arguments = "-version";
java.Start();

// version comes out null
string version = java.StandardError.ReadLine();

// There are probably better ways to extract this data but
// I want to get it working before I cross that bridge.
string versionNumber = version.Substring(16, 1);

java.Close();
```

Comment: Indeed, I just discovered that myself as you were typing this (See my commend on Dmitry Ledentsov's answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can read the currently installed Java version from the registry as well. The following file includes the method `TryGetJavaHome`, which supports 32- and 64-bit virtual machines for specific vendor/installation combinations.

```
bool TryGetJavaHome(
    RegistryView registryView,
    string vendor,
    string installation,
    out string javaHome)
```

Vendors:

- "JavaSoft" (HotSpot)
- "JRockit"

Installations:

- "Java Runtime Environment"
- "Java Development Kit"

If you look at the code for the method, you'll find the following line which obtains the current version.

```
object currentVersion = javaKey.GetValue("CurrentVersion");
```

This will return a value like "1.7" or "1.6". If want a more complete version number, *some* installations provide the following.

```
object familyVersion6 = javaKey.GetValue("Java6FamilyVersion");
object familyVersion7 = javaKey.GetValue("Java7FamilyVersion");
```

For some installations, the family version is not present, but for the standard runtime installation I see the values "1.6.0_38" and "1.7.0_13".

**Reference:** [Antlr4ClassGenerationTaskInternal.cs](https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs/blob/master/runtime/CSharp/Antlr4BuildTasks/Antlr4ClassGenerationTaskInternal.cs)

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `java.CreateNoWindow = true;`, it works.

Comment: It still does not work for me. Very peculiar that it works for you.

Comment: works even in an online compiler: http://ideone.com/yWsBtP
This one can even call java http://www.compileonline.com/compile_csharp_online.php

Comment: which brings me to another idea, try redirecting and reading StandardError as well! Maybe java wrote to stderr instead of stdout

Comment: Good idea, for some reason when I debug the error, I find the output. Very strange, but I can work with it. http://i.imgur.com/trfifPK.png Very weird